# Switching windows at runtime in GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

```
int
main()
{
  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
  auto window = glfwCreateWindow(1080, 720, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);   
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  gladLoadGL();

  while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == false) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
      glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_P) == GLFW_PRESS) {
      glfwDestroyWindow(window);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
      window = glfwCreateWindow(1080, 720, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    }

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //draw

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  glfwTerminate();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I hit `p` I want to change my window to a resizeable window, but the problem that I have is that nothing gets drawn on the new window while glClear still seems to be working.

I assume that something went wrong with the OpenGL context. I am currently using [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) to load my OpenGL context.

Do I have to do something else to swap a window in glfw?

Comment: Does `window` return a valid pointer the second time? And have you tried checking `glGetError` after each relevant line? You can also try setting `glfwSetErrorCallback`.

Comment: glGetError returns 0 and glfwSetErrorCallback doesn't get called

Comment: `glGetError` returns 0 *after* your `//draw` code?

Comment: @Rotem yes after and before.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work either (using GLEW), but at the very least, you would need to share the objects between the old context and the new one, by passing the old window as the last parameter in `glfwCreateWindow`.

Comment: If I explicitly change the context with the old window, then I get `INVALID_OPERATION` from glGetError.